# Swift DataModel - Keep losing Atribuites

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, datamodel

I have a DataModel in my App and for the third time a entity loose a attribute. If i take a look in the DataModel2.xcdatamodeld i can see the attribute there, but when i print my NSEntityDescription i can´t see the attribute there. I already delete the app from the simulator, clean the project, close Xcode and the problem persist.
It was everything working yesterday, today my app is crashing because i can´t save or fetch the database with the missing attribute "title".

My DataModel
[image]

My NSEntityDescription, you can see that i don´t have the attribute "title" anymore

```
  Optional((<NSEntityDescription: 0x144612d70>) name Movies, managedObjectClassName NSManagedObject, renamingIdentifier Movies, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {
    country = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144529b00>), name country, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier country, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    dateadded = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x1445299e0>), name dateadded, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier dateadded, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName NSDate, defaultValue (null)";
    file = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x1445298c0>), name file, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier file, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    genre = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144613410>), name genre, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier genre, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    host = "(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x144528a20>), name host, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier host, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, destination entity Hosts2, inverseRelationship movies, minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1";
    label = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144528880>), name label, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier label, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    movieid = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144529b90>), name movieid, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier movieid, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
    mpaa = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144528c10>), name mpaa, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier mpaa, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    originaltitle = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144528910>), name originaltitle, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier originaltitle, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    playcount = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144507eb0>), name playcount, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier playcount, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
    plot = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144528ca0>), name plot, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier plot, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    rating = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144529950>), name rating, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier rating, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    thumbnail = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144703cb0>), name thumbnail, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier thumbnail, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    trailer = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144529a70>), name trailer, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier trailer, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)";
    year = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x144613300>), name year, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Movies, renamingIdentifier year, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 200 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0";
}, subentities {
}, userInfo {
}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (
))
```

This is the third time that this happen and i have to remove the data model and create again to fix it. Even if i delete the attribute it will not work because any other attribute that i insert it will not be in the NSEntityDescription. There is a way to fix this without have to delete the entire DataModel ? Thank´s in advance.

Comment: Do you happen to have multiple datamodel versions? Like: DataModel1.xcdatamodeld and DataModel2.xcdatamodeld

Comment: If you have multiple versions of the data model, you need to specify which one is active.

Comment: I just open the DataModel.xcdatamodeld in Finder and take a look. There are 3 DataModel there, i don´t know why. The names are DataModel2 (1).xcdatamodel,  DataModel2 (2).xcdatamodel and DataModel2.xcdatamodel . For some reason my project is using the DataModel2 (1).xcdatamodel and in this one i don´t have the attribute "title". I jus delete the files that i don´t want and seems that everything is working fine now. Thank´s very much.

Comment: Those `(1)`, `(2)`, etc, sound like you're getting conflicting file versions, probably from a file syncing service like Dropbox or something similar. Conflicting file versions are going to be a problem in all sorts of ways until you figure out why they're happening and prevent them.

Comment: you are right @Tom Harrington. I forgot to pause Google Drive.